# How to turn a list of string into dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how do I separate a list of string and turn it into a dataframe?
From this format:

```
['x data,y data',
 '-969.0,-52.12282,',
 '-959.0,-49.436077,',
 '-948.0,-46.615,',
 '-938.0,-44.59994,',
 ]
```

To a dataframe like this(The first row will be the dataframe column header):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

lst = ['x data,y data',
       '-969.0,-52.12282,',
       '-959.0,-49.436077,',
       '-948.0,-46.615,',
       '-938.0,-44.59994,',
       ]

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(s[:-1] for s in lst)))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   x data      y dat
0  -969.0 -52.122820
1  -959.0 -49.436077
2  -948.0 -46.615000
3  -938.0 -44.599940
```

Comment: Why the generator? Can't you just `'\n'.join(lst)`?

Comment: Need to remove the trailing comma

Comment: Without removing trailing comma works, give a try to my answer, just add `index_col=False`

Comment: I made some adjustment for your solution and it deliver the result that i want. `df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(s for s in data[0])),index_col=False)`

Comment: @wkwkwk if you are using `index_col=False` then you can just use `'\n'.join(lst)`

Comment: @WasifHasan got it

Answer (score 2):

My try using `io.StringIO`+`.read_csv`:

```
s = ['x data,y data',
 '-969.0,-52.12282,',
 '-959.0,-49.436077,',
 '-948.0,-46.615,',
 '-938.0,-44.59994,',
 ]
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(s)),index_col=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea in list comprehension:

```
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in data[1:]], columns=data[0].split(','))  

print (df)
   x data     y data
0  -969.0 -52.122820
1  -959.0 -49.436077
2  -948.0 -46.615000
3  -938.0 -44.599940
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x.strip(',').split(',') for x in data[1:]], columns=data[0].split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple way to do it would be :-

```
lst = ['x data,y data',
       '-969.0,-52.12282,',
       '-959.0,-49.436077,',
       '-948.0,-46.615,',
       '-938.0,-44.59994,',
       ]
lst[0]=lst[0]+','
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#Reshape it having 2 columns
lst=list(map(lambda x: x[:-1].split(','), lst))
np_array_1=np.array(lst).reshape(-1,2)
#Create DataFrame
df=pd.DataFrame(data=np_array_1[1:,:],columns=np_array_1[0,:])
#You may convert data type now
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution from Dani Mesejo and Wasif Hasan

```
import io


   list = ['x data,y data',
 '-970.0,-34.12164,',
 '-959.0,-32.37526,',
 '-949.0,-30.360199,',
 ]
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(data[0])),index_col=False)
```

Output:

```
   x data    y data
0  -970.0 -34.121640
1  -959.0 -32.375260
2  -949.0 -30.360199
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```py
import pandas
z = ['x data,y data',
       '-969.0,-52.12282,',
       '-959.0,-49.436077,',
       '-948.0,-46.615,',
       '-938.0,-44.59994,',
       ]
df = []

# Split based on commas

for i in z:
    df.append(i.split(',')[0:2])

# Convert to Dataframe

final_df = pandas.DataFrame(df[1:], columns=df[0])
```

I splited the data based on commas by using the split command.